# Segment Fault and Shared Library usage - Vega 7000 POS

Tags: c, netbeans, segmentation-fault, point-of-sale

I am a newbie on Castles Technologies and Vega products and I am using it for the very first time. I have to modify an existing Vega7000 Application. It uses shared library so that the application is splitted into two MCI files (one for program and another for share lib).

When I try and create an helloWorld application it works properly and I can display it on the device but when I try and launch this application (which is a formed by 2 applications, VegaApplication + SharedVegaApplication) I get this error "**Segment Fault ADDR 0X000383A4**".

These are the used technologies:
NetBeans, Windows XP, Cygwin, gcc-mipsel, C language, Vega 7000

My questions are:

1. how to properly use a **Shared Application** on such environment
2. What can be the reason of this "Segment Fault" error

I cannot get any log from this device so I cannot get any more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help someone else to know that I solved the **Segment Fault Error** by increasing the size of the CAP files when performing the CAP Generation. I increased these values:

1. AP Flash Size
2. Flash FAT Size
3. SRAM FAT Size

   They has to be set according to your specific application and device that you use and the best value changes accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution. I want to start developing VEGA 7000  POS-s too. But I can't find any SDK or Plugin for it in its website. May I ask you to refer me somewhere that I can find some useful info. What is the Cygwin for? (In your question)

Comment: cygwin is a set of linux tools to be used on windows. This might help: https://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: I searched that website, but found nothing! May I ask you to refer me to a download link please?

Comment: http://www.castech.com.tw/EN/in-download-02.aspx?wcid=C_00000030&id=P_00000058&cid=C_00000024

Comment: What is this? Is it a SDK for **EFT-POS VEGA 7000**?! It is a SDK for smart card reader!

Comment: yes you are right; sorry, then I dont know where to download it. I would open a new S.O. question

Comment: thank you for posting, i want to start programming for vega7000,i don't find any user manual and SDK, can you help me. thanks